# Collaborative authoring of LaTeX document

Tags: collaboration

I am authoring a LaTeX document with a co-author. The document is a single, monolithic one. We are working on two separate copies of the same document. Once one of us is done with his section, we are merging it together and updating out local copies. It has become a headache. Is there a better way to collaborate authoring LaTeX document?

Comment: Are you using a version control system such as git?

Comment: Online via sharelatex.com comes to mind, or use a version contaol system like subversion or git.

Comment: Well there are on-line services such as [WriteLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/) or [ShareLaTeX](https://es.sharelatex.com/) that can be useful for this cases. You can use also a cvs such as Git for that (take a look to [GitHub](https://github.com/)) or a service in the cloud like Dropbox, Copy, etc. That's what I use in cases like this.

Comment: If I use SVN, would it be fine while merging the documents considering that no two authors have changed the same line?

Comment: SVN will let you know if there are any conflicts (for example if you've both edited the same line). See the [Resolve Any Conflicts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve) section of the svn book for further details.